# Tabs In Google Chrome Have gotten clobbered, How to reset?

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason, my tabs have gotten crunched on my google chrome browser (see picture attached). I've try to go into settings and reset browser but it does not change.  I'm running windows 8.1 with my fonts at 150% because I have big monitors.

Version 31.0.1650.63 m

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did some more searching and found the answer (though it makes the screen pretty ugly, google does not do a good job with this)

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BnI6QInBHC4

"I found the answer posted by Azmeer Kahn on November 22.  Type chrome://flags in the address and scroll WAY down to the HiDPI section - change from default to Enable.  Whew.  Worked for me."

Answer (score 0):

Are these tabs pinned? I had similar problems with pinned tabs in early versions of chrome. Unpinning and pinning again might help then.

Comment: not sure where to find pinned? I don't have "sync tabs" enabled, and, when I run in icongnite mode I do not get this behavior.

Comment: If you right click on them, there is a context menu item called "Pin Tab" respectively "Unpin Tab". Might help, but it's strange that it works in incognito mode.

Comment: They all say "pin" when I right click which I assume means they are not pinned.